# Caching UDP packets with iptables

Tags: iptables, cache, internet, udp

I have a server set up to forward all of its packets on a certain port to another host with the following command;
`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport PORT -j DNAT --to-destination IP:PORT`

There's quite a delay caused by this due to how far away the servers are from eachother, and the data is almost always the same. I was wondering if iptables has some kind of method so if it receives a UDP packet, it can cache the response and then send that back to all identical requests.

For example, if the server receives "hello" in a UDP packet, it then forwards it to another server and receives "world" from that server (as all of it's traffic on that port is forwarded). Then I want it to respond with "world" everytime it receives "hello" **without** forwarding it to the second server again. Eg, all subsequent requests are cached.

Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No. You would not be able to do that with `iptables`. What you're wanting would require writing an actual program to listen on those ports and interact with the packets on its own, as well as tracking key:value pairs for the instant response.